# Data bind a LINQ query to a DataGridView that will also update the db

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I have a DataGridView that I want to bind to a LINQ query where it will update the database.

First I had something like this

```
        //Select the values I want which include using a Navigation Property
        var query = from c in _data.OrdersTables
                    where c.FamilyID == _familyID
                    select new { c.ItemInfo.ItemName, c.Requested, c.Paid };

        var results = query.ToList();
        dataGridViewOrderInfo.DataSource = results;
```

This works fine for displaying data but when you use select new it kills the connection to the database and you have to use the new statement to select specific columns. 
Now I have this

```
        var query = from c in _data.OrdersTables
                    where c.FamilyID == _familyID
                    select c;

        var results = query.ToList();
        dataGridViewOrderInfo.DataSource = results;
```

I just pull the entire row in and then hide the columns I don't want and this works for displaying and editing the values, but only the ones that are in the OrdersTables. I can't use the navigation property to join to another table and display data from it.

I have tried just editing the row header but it won't let me and I also have tried adding a new column but again won't let me. I imagine because the grid is already bound. Extra info the db specified is a sql ce. So I just need a way to bind the datagrid to a custom select statement that might pull from multiple tables. I thought I could maybe make some sort of a view in my .edmx file but I couldn't see a way to do that. I also thought I could just make a database view but I don't think I can with SQL CE.

Comment: did you try this: from c in _data.OrdersTables.Include("ItemInfo")

Comment: when I add that it doesn't seem to change anything. @Tim.Tang

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide cloumn,set datagridview.

Comment: If I understand what your saying, I can already hide columns that does not provide a solution, as stated in my question.